# Python Requests gets different HTML data than Browser; JS seems irrelevant

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the weather data from this website:

http://www.fastweather.com/yesterday.php?city=St.+Louis_MO

The problem I have run into is Yesterday's Precipitation. When viewed in the developer tools, I see the following:

```
<strong>Yesterday's Precipitation</strong>
was 0.13 inches
```

But when viewing it from Python, either using Requests or the urllib modules, I see this:

```
<strong>Yesterday\'s Precipitation</strong>
was T inches
```

I use NoScript in my browser, and I disallowed all JavaScript from running, but the 0.13 still appears. Where is this number coming from, and how do I obtain it with Python?

I'm on a Unix system, and this will be a daily script to run. I would like to avoid Selenium, if possible.

Even if there are other websites to use, I would like to know why that mysterious T exists.

---

Here's my relevant code:

```
webpage = requests.get("http://www.fastweather.com/yesterday.php?city=St.+Louis_MO")
if webpage.status_code == 200:
    content = str(webpage.content)
```

I have also tried this:

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    webpage = session.get("http://www.fastweather.com/yesterday.php?city=St.+Louis_MO")
    content = webpage.text
```

And this:

```
webpage = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.fastweather.com/yesterday.php?city=St.+Louis_MO")
content = webpage.read()
```

(There may be minor mistakes in the above code since I can't remember exactly how each method works.)

Comment: Show your code. I can clearly see `was 0.13 inches` when using Requests

Comment: I added my code.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code to get required output:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

response = requests.get('http://www.fastweather.com/yesterday.php?city=St.+Louis_MO')
source = html.fromstring(response.text)
text_node = source.xpath('//div[@id="content"]//strong[.="Yesterday\'s Precipitation"]/following-sibling::text()[1]')[0]
print(text_node.strip())  # 'was 0.13 inches'
```

Comment: This won't work. I checked the response.text, and the T is right there. Or does using lxml.html.fromstring() change that T somehow?

Comment: Have no idea :) I just can't reproduce your issue and get `"was T inches"`... I see `"was 0.13 inches"` in output